# Simultaneous equations help

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I have the following:

```
rhohat = I*omega*v;
rhobar = I*omega*vbar;
lambdaplus = eta + zeta;
lambdaneg = eta - zeta;
lambdabarplus = etabar + zetabar;
lambdabarneg = etabar - zetabar;
```

and the equations

```
xi = I*zetabar^.5*b*Exp[lambdabarplus*x3] - 
   I*zetabar^.5*a*Exp[lambdabarneg*x3];
tau = I*rhobar*zetabar^-.5*b*Exp[lambdabarplus*x3] + 
   I*rhobar*zetabar^-.5*a*Exp[lambdabarneg*x3];
```

I want to solve for a and b. I tried using

```
Solve[{xi, tau}, {a, b}]
```

but didn't work. Could anyone help please?

Comment: You didn't define equations! Try something like `Solve[{xi==0, tau==0}, {a, b}]`. But what is `{a,b}`??

Comment: This did not work!

Comment: a and b are terms in the equations xi and tau

Comment: `Solve[{xi == 0, tau == 0}, {a, b}]` evaluates to `{{a -> 0., b -> 0.}}`

Comment: Note that you'll likely have to clear the kernel of the definitions of `xi` and `tau` before running the `Solve` code above in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rhohat = I*omega*v;
rhobar = I*omega*vbar;
lambdaplus = eta + zeta;
lambdaneg = eta - zeta;
lambdabarplus = etabar + zetabar;
lambdabarneg = etabar - zetabar;
```

Equations require the use of [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) ( == ) rather than [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) ( = )

```
eqns = {xi == 
    I*zetabar^(1/2)*b*Exp[lambdabarplus*x3] - 
     I*zetabar^(1/2)*a*Exp[lambdabarneg*x3],
   tau == I*rhobar*zetabar^(-1/2)*b*Exp[lambdabarplus*x3] + 
     I*rhobar*zetabar^(-1/2)*a*Exp[lambdabarneg*x3]} // Simplify;

sol = Solve[eqns, {a, b}][[1]] // Simplify

(* {a -> -((E^(x3 (-etabar + zetabar)) (-I omega vbar xi + tau zetabar))/(
   2 omega vbar Sqrt[zetabar])), 
 b -> -((E^(-x3 (etabar + zetabar)) (I omega vbar xi + tau zetabar))/(
   2 omega vbar Sqrt[zetabar]))} *)
```

Verifying the solution

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. When I run this code however I get empty brackets? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ignore my comment, I am dumb.